# Text on top of lines

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get text to show above some horizontal lines. But try as I might the text always show underneath.

Here is the code
http://jsfiddle.net/mrchin/uTsxZ/

Can anyone see what I need to do? I've always done layout in flash and am still learning css. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positioning the text relatively seems to work:

```
#txt_projects
{
   position: relative;   
}
```

Comment: That did it. positioning is a little bit difficult for me still. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use background image to display lines underneath the text.

I updated your code, please review.
http://jsfiddle.net/uTsxZ/4/

if you need a tripple line, you need to modify your background image to do that.